# Adjust the size of a shape based on seekbar progress

Tags: android

I currently am trying to use the `SeekBar` to change the size of a ring: as the value of the `SeekBar` increases, I would like the size of the ring to increase. However, when I use the code below, the shape size does not change. Does anyone know how to make this work?

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView textview3;
SeekBar tipSeekBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tipSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    tipSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(tipSeekBarListener);
}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener tipSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textview3.setHeight((int) (tipSeekBar.getProgress()));
        textview3.setWidth((int) (tipSeekBar.getProgress()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textview3.setHeight((int) (tipSeekBar.getProgress()));
        textview3.setWidth((int) (tipSeekBar.getProgress()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textview3.setHeight((int) (tipSeekBar.getProgress()));
        textview3.setWidth((int) (tipSeekBar.getProgress()));
    }

};
```

xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circgraya" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ring_unfilled_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:background="#CC0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="10"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is making the `SeekBar` progress?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils the user moving it..

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere; you're code, as written, works for me. Add your layout.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils xml file added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="200dp" <---
    android:layout_height="200dp" <---
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ring_unfilled_gray" />
```

You've set the size explicitly, so it seems it won't override it as it would min, max(s), and wrapping content.

This works for me (changing the size of the text view via the seek bar that is)...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" <---
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <---
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="I'll get bigger soon..." /> <-- notice no background!
```

However, this is a hack. A text view probably isn't what you want. I didn't use an image because the image isn't important to controlling the height and width of the text view. An image would be more appropriate I believe. I think you'll find, once you get it "working", it might not behave as you would like.

Also -

You could be doing some unnecessary things here. My code that handles the progress change is like so (names changed to mine now)...

```
...
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        mTextView.setHeight(progress);
        mTextView.setWidth(progress);
    }
}
...
```

As you can tell I don't...cast an `int` to an `int`, `getProgress()` - I've already got it, or instantiate a new `TextView` for each change and gesture. You're actually allocating two new `TextView`s on a gesture; one at the start, and one at the end. You may want to keep a member `TextView` to hang on to and refer to the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) to know what API methods you're using are doing, the parameters they provide, and their proper usage.